# iOS - search the number and scroll at that position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I tried realize custom search bar in tableview. My table consist of numbers.
In the search bar, I want enter the number from table of which I want to find and click the search button -> table scroll at the position of the number.
But I don't understand how to do it. And I could not find anything on the Internet. Maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be that you have a model which you use for dataSource of **tableView**.
I'm close to absolutely sure, it's an array.

So, to scroll you need 2 steps:

- 1) Find an **index** of element you've entered in **searchBar**. This can be done by looping though your array and comparing each elements with one you've entered (or use **filter** function)
- 2) If something found (elements exists), make an **IndexPath**-type
  variable with that index and **section 0** (if your **tableView** has one
  section - by default it do), and call the method **scrollToRow** of **tableView**

Example:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I've searched for "**4**"

```
if let intToSearch = Int(searchString),
   let index = numbers.index(of: intToSearch) {
    let path = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: path, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a table view we provide it a data source. Which is some collection of objects. When you "search" you're determining if an object in our collection is relevant to the search term. This is some sort of comparison based off your design.

So you could either make a second "filtered" collection and tell the table to update (displaying only relevant search results). Or you could find the first match and tell your table view to scroll to that index. With tableview:scrolltoindex